# How to secure the wcf web service with the use of ACS(Azure)

Tags: wcf, azure, web, single-sign-on, token

Would like to know how I can enable my wcf web service to provide encryption and authenication? Currently, my web service is connected to Azure(ACS) and ask the identity provider for authentication checking, I can implement the ssl tunneling for getting username and password. but how I can get the acs token and perform SSO? I want to know any current implementation or is there any good example to follow?

Many thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a codeplex project with some great documentation.

http://acs.codeplex.com/documentation

When you mention SSO, I'm assuming you mean federated authentication with active directory. If so, there's a sample project available on MDSN with an example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127796.aspx

Answer (score 0):

lot's of useful information and samples here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185912.aspx